# Yocto does not install files to /usr/share

Tags: yocto

The yocto recipe `hplip_3.18.6.bb` does not unzip and install the `ppd` files to `/usr/share/ppd/HP`. So I added my own recipe `hplip_%.bbappend`.

I performed `bitbake base-image -c rootfs` and see the unzipped `ppd` files in `/yocto/build/tmp/work/armv7ahf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/hplip/3.18.6-r1/hplip-3.18.6/ppd/hpcups"

I see the installed files under `/yocto/build/tmp/work/armv7ahf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/hplip/3.18.6-r1/image`.

But the files are not in `/yocto/build/tmp/work/poky-linux-gnueabi/base-image/1.0-r0/rootfs`

I tried with other files (.sh) but same result: install does not work for `/usr/share`  but works for e.g. `/etc/udev/scripts` I can install my custom scripts or the `ppd` files into `${sysconfdir}` but not into `${datadir}`

I reviewed `PACKAGES += "${PN}-ppd ${PN}-cups ${PN}-backend ${PN}-filter ${PN}-hal"` and it seems ok.

My `hplip_%.bbappend`:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Install additional files for hplip"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "bash"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

# The udev rules and script to install a hp printer connected over Usb
SRC_URI += " \
    file://etc/udev/rules.d/60-install-hp-usb.rules \
    file://etc/udev/scripts/install-hp-usb.sh \
"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_append := "${WORKDIR}/${BP}/ppd/hpcups/:"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_append := "${D}/${datadir}/:"

do_install_append() {
    # Install of udev rules and script
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/udev/rules.d
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/etc/udev/rules.d/60-install-hp-usb.rules ${D}${sysconfdir}/udev/rules.d/60-install-hp-usb.rules
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/udev/scripts
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/etc/udev/scripts/install-hp-usb.sh ${D}${sysconfdir}/udev/scripts/install-hp-usb.sh

    bbwarn datadir=${D}/${datadir}
    bbwarn sysconfdir=${D}/${sysconfdir}

    # Extract and install the ppds
    install -d ${D}/${datadir}/ppd/HP
    for file in $(ls -1 ${WORKDIR}/${BP}/ppd/hpcups/*.gz); do
        archive=`basename $file`
        ppdFile=${archive%.gz}
        gunzip -c ${WORKDIR}/${BP}/ppd/hpcups/${archive} > ${WORKDIR}/${BP}/ppd/hpcups/${ppdFile}
        install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/${BP}/ppd/hpcups/${ppdFile} ${D}/${datadir}/ppd/HP/${ppdFile}
    done
}
```

Comment: upstream recipe says `FILES_${PN}-ppd = "${datadir}/ppd"` so it does seem to install something in the package hplip-ppd. That's where your appended files would end in as well. When you say "I'm not able to install" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: There are files in  package/usr/share/ppd/HP but not in the rootfs/usr/share/ppd/HP.

Comment: To debug such a thing you should use yocto buildhistory, you can easily identify if and where your files installed. I guess the files are in a different package then you expect.  Did you get something like "WARNING: QA Issue: Files/directories were installed but not shipped" ?

Comment: I do not get the "WARNING: QA Issue: Files/directories were installed but not shipped". But I verified this possible error with another file.

Comment: Have you tried adding `FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}/ppd/HP/"` ?